# Yocto, bitbake, how to avoid rebuilding a component

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Component-A depends on Component-B,
I do some change to Component-B and I am sure the change does not impact Component-A,
since rebuilding Component-A requires some time,
I wonder, is it possible to avoid rebuilding Component-A when build a final image?

Comment: You could add `SIGGEN_EXCLUDE_SAFE_RECIPE_DEPS += "ComponentA->Component-B"` to local.conf to ignore the change from Component-B when building Component-A. Remember to remove it when you make a breaking change to Component-B. Note: after you add this, Component-A most probably will be rebuilt at least one more time, with ignoring Component-B. [Docs here.](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-SIGGEN_EXCLUDE_SAFE_RECIPE_DEPS)